# echo special characters to a file in bash

Tags: bash, shell, echo

I am trying to make a script to help me back port source code to debian files.

trying to write debian/rules file

```
~$ echo -e  "#!/usr/bin/make -f\n%:\n\tdh \$@" > debian/rules
bash: !/usr/bin/make: event not found
```

i think the # and ! are screwing this up. How can I echo these components of the string without having the shell try to execute them?
I have tried using "#" and "!"  but then i would get the exactly that: "!"

I want a rules file that looks exactly like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
%:
    dh $@
```

what should I do?

Comment: This is due to history expansion and is only an issue when you run commands interactively. If you had put that line in a script and run the script, it would have been fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

! is not escaped by double quotes

```
'#!/usr/bin/make -f\n%:\n\tdh \'"$@"
```

should be fine. However, please look at here-documents:

```
cat <<MAKEFILE
#!/usr/bin/make -f
%:
    dh $@
MAKEFILE
```

Comment: `man bash` is my place to go; there are several sites dedicated to shell scripting and/or bash, so you should be able to find much more in the way of examples too

Comment: Looking at the expected output in the question, OP does not seem to want to expand `"$@"`...

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternative method, using ANSI hex codes (or even Unicode hex codes, if you're clever).

```
$ echo -e "\x23\x21/usr/bin/make -f\n\x25:\n\tdh \x24\x40"
#!/usr/bin/make -f
%:
        dh $@
```

My method makes a bit more intuitive sense to me, though the use of [here documents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) by @sehe is ingenious. (It would also require less look-ups if you're not very familiar with ANSI.) I needed to know that `#` is `U+0023`; that `!` is `U+0021`; etc. I work with Unicode codepoints all the time, so it's quick.